# How does sunlight undergo interference as shown in the video?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, wave-particle-duality

As far as I know, for interference to happen in a double-slit experiment, the light source should be coherent and monochromatic.

If that is the case then how come sunlight undergo interference and forms the same pattern (with just a rainbowing effect) as shown in the video. Sunlight is not monochromatic...

The video: https://youtu.be/Iuv6hY6zsd0

I think we can say the small slits makes the light coherent in nature but am confused about the monochromatic part.

Is there any thing am missing in the interpretation?

Comment: Given that interference was known and observed before the invention of the laser, why do you believe that coherence and monochromaticity are required?

Comment: White light is far from monochromatic but how that gives rise to the observed rainbow effect is fairly well explained in the video. What happens is similar to using a diffraction grating to separate the different wavelengths of white light: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_grating

Comment: There are two types of coherence: spatial and temporal. Diffraction experiments with slits only require spatial coherence, since your eye can't resolve the correlations in the photon statistics at the nanosecond to attosecond level. If you are interested in testing temporal coherence, then you need an interferometer, which is also an interference experiment, but one that requires temporal, rather than spatial coherence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.

First consider how the different lights colors interact with each other, please see [additive color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color) for an explanation.

Then if you consider a [double slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment) as shown on wikipedia with coherent monochromatic light.

Now we know that sunlight is composed by continium of wavelength of slightly different colors, but you can think of it as many different coherent lasers of different colors.

Now for each color independently you will have a diffraction pattern similar to the one on the wikipedia page, but since each color has a different wavelength, the patterns are different (the distance between the peaks is related to the wavelength), so you will have:

1. Spots where no light arrives from any of the colors
2. Spots where only a specific color arrives
3. Spots where several colors will arrive at the same time, so you will see white.

I hope this can clarify the issue

Regards

PS: It was a very cool video